MySQL and JDBC connection to Azure for MySQL using SSL without modifying Java code
I have a Java application that I don't have the source code to.  I do have a configuration file that is pointed at a local MySQL server instance.  The connectionstring was
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/databasename .
I moved the MySQL database up to Azure for MySQL flexible server.  I know I have comm from the application server to the Azure instance because I used MySQL workbench to transfer the database.
I then changed my connection string to
jdbc:mysql://myname.mysql.database.azure.com:3306/databaseName?useSSL=true

When booting the application, I can see the error message 'Communications link failure'.
I read here that in order to communicate via SSL to the Azure for MySQL flexible server instance, I needed to download the PEM file here.  I did.
However, I do not have access to the source, so I cannot setup the Java code how the MSDN article presents.  I only have access to the connection string.
I downloaded the PEM file into the root of c:.
I then ran keytool -importcert -alias mysql -file c:\DigiCertGlobalRootCA.crt.pem -keystore mycerts -storepass changeit
I then updated the connection string to be
jdbc:mysql://myname.mysql.database.azure.com:3306/databaseName?useSSL=true&amp;verifyServerCertificate=true&amp;trustCertificateKeyStoreUrl=C:/jdk/jdk17/lib/security/cacerts&amp;trustCertificateKeyStorePassword=changeit

My error message when booting up now Could not create connection to database server.  I have verified the location of the cacerts keystore location and password and can view the entry in the keytool command line tool.
Is it possible to update a MySQL connection string, run through JDBC, to use SSL without modifying the underlying JAVA code?  Is there another combination of parameters I can use on the connection string to make the SSL handshake work?

You are importing the pem into mycerts.jks but referencing cacerts instead?

Good catch @aled!  Where do I find where that import statement created the jks file?  I don't see it in the same directory (java home/security)

In the directory where you executed it. Also for me it is not a best practice to modify files inside the JDK directory. Create a directory somewhere else and reference it.

Do you really have &amp; in your connection string? I think it should be just &.

And you have useSSL=true twice.

The configuration is in XML, so yes, it is &.

My bad on the typo, removing duplicate.
